# What do we call a person who doesn't know their talent?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have one friend who always underestimates her knowledge and talent. We always have to encourage her that she can do it.
I always wonder if there is a word that would describe this behavior? I tried but I can't find a proper word for it.

Comment: For single word requests you should include a sample sentence with a space where the selected word can be inserted.

Comment: The missing part of Rumsfeld's system: the unknown knowns.

Answer (score 2):

You could say that she [undervalues herself](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/undervalue):

> to consider something to have less worth or importance than it really has

A related phrase (but not a single word) is [to sell oneself short](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sell-sb-yourself-sth-short).